# Uncaught TypeError: init is not a function at mountLazyComponent

Tags: reactjs, react-suspense

I am trying to add a suspense to my reactjs app and I got this error. Not really sure what I am doing wrong. It looks like previous Suspense that I have used but this time it is erroring. I'm not sure if it has to do with the index.js file but I will happily post that if it is needed to answer the question

````
const Projects = lazy(() => import('./pages/Projects/Projects'));
import Loader from "./components/UI/Loader/Loader";


const App = ({ loggedIn, emailVerified }) => {
  let routes;
  if (loggedIn && !emailVerified) {
    routes = (
      <Layout>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/verify-email" component={VerifyEmail} />
          <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
          <Redirect to="/verify-email" />
        </Switch>
   
      </Layout>
    );
  } else if (loggedIn && emailVerified) {
    routes = (
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Projects} />
          <Route exact path ="/verify-email" 
          render={() =>
            emailVerified ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Profile />
          }
          />
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
          <Route path="/:id" component={TodosLayout} />
        
          <Redirect to="/" />
          </Suspense>
        </Switch>
 
      </Layout>
    );
  } else {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        Other routes I removed for length
      </Switch>
    );
  }
  return <Fragment>{routes}</Fragment>;
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Modules must be imported at the bottom.

For Examle:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// import anything else here like: 
import Loader from "./components/UI/Loader/Loader";

// import lazy modules at the very bottom
const Projects = lazy(() => import('./pages/Projects/Projects'));

const App = () => {
  return <h3>App Is Working</h3>
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I switched it to the bottom and still have the same error

Comment: You aren't actually referencing the `Projects` component here. That's why it's not throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to issue with the react version. If you are using 16.14 please downgrade to 16.13 or update to  "react": "^17.0.2",

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).